# kubectl copy logs from pod when terminating

Tags: kubernetes, logging

We are trying to get the logs of pods after multiple restarts but we dont want to use any external solution like efk.

i tried below config but its not working. does the below cmd run on the pod or it will run on node level

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
  exec:
       command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "kubectl logs appworks-0 > /container-stoped.txt"]
```

Comment: The `-p`option of `kubectl logs`will give you the logs of the previous instance of a container (the one that failed).

Answer (score 1):

> i tried below config but its not working. does the below cmd run on
> the pod or it will run on node level

it will run on the POD level, not on **Node** level

You can use the **Hostpath** in POD configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:  
  - image: alpine
    name: test-container
    command: ["tail"]
    args: ["-f", "/dev/null"] 
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /host
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /
      type: Directory
```

**Hostpath** will directly will create one Dir at the Node level and save logs over there, if you don't want this solution you can add your solution of **lifecycle hook** also however when you can directly write app logs to Host don't add lifecycle hook extra.

**Note** : Make sure if your Node goes down **hostpath** or **emptyDir** logs you will miss.